# select dropdown issue in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

```js
$scope.vehicles = [ {
   id : 'vehicle1'
  } ];
$scope.addNewVehicle = function() {
   var newItemNo = $scope.vehicles.length + 1;
   // var n = $scope.vehicles.length -1;
   $scope.vehicles.push({
    'id' : 'vehicle' + newItemNo
   });
 $scope.getdetail = function(vin, index) { 
$scope['typeOptions' + index] = d.data.vehicleVINDetailsFeed.trims; 
$scope.trim[vehicle.id] = $scope['typeOptions' + index][0];
   }
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-6  text-right">
      <a ng-click="addNewVehicle()" class="btn btn-link"
       id="add-newvehicle" style="color:#0000ff; cursor:pointer">add new</a>
     </div>
<div class="col-lg-12 form-content vin-inner"
      ng-repeat="vehicle in vehicles">
  <input type="text" class="form-control"
          ng-class="{redBorder: (registrationForm.$submitted && !registrationForm.vin{{$index}}.$valid)}"
          ng-model="vin[vehicle.id]" name="vin{{$index}}" placeholder="VIN" required
          maxlength="17">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-info"
          id="registration-preview" ng-click="getdetail(vin[vehicle.id], $index)">
          review
         </button>
<select class="trim-select" ng-model="trim[vehicle.id]"
         name="trim{{$index}}" id="trim{{$index}}"
         ng-options='option as option for option in typeOptions{{$index}}'
         ng-change="changeDetails($index, trim[vehicle.id])">
        </select>
  </div
```

if I click on add "add new" link vin inputbox, review button and select box will repeat and it is working as expected. if you enter the vin number in the vin field and click on review the selcet dropdown is loading the date from the restAPI response, that part also working fine. My problem is i want to select the first option will be default selected. So even if you add more vin input sessions, and click on preview of corresponding vin input the select option should load with corresponding response and first option should select default.  I can't create it in plunker since there are lot of server dependence

I hope I convey my issue.Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: may i know what is d here..

    $scope['typeOptions' + index] = d.data.vehicleVINDetailsFeed.trims;

Comment: d.data.vehicleVINDetailsFeed.trims will have value from the server response like ["SE 4dr Sedan (2.0L 4cyl 5M)","GLS PZEV 4dr Sedan (2.0L 4cyl 4A)","GLS 4dr Sedan (2.0L 4cyl 4A)","GLS 4dr Sedan (2.0L 4cyl 5M)","SE PZEV 4dr Sedan (2.0L 4cyl 4A)","SE 4dr Sedan (2.0L 4cyl 4A)"] and using that values I am making my select dropdown